# sum total of values inside dynamic inputs with same class and Auto re-sum total of values when I change any input values or add / delete dynamic row

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, sum

```js
$("#add-btn").click(function() {
  $("#dynamic").append('<tr>' +
    '<td class="td">' +
    '<input type="number" name="Debit" class="form-control Debit"/>' +
    '</td>' +
    '<td class = "td" >' +
    '<input type = "number" class = "form-control credit" />' +
    '</td>' +
    '<td class = "td2" >' +
    '<button type = "button" name = "add" class = "btn btn-danger remove-tr" > Remove </button>' +
    '</td>' +
    '</tr>');
});

$(document).on('click', '.remove-tr', function() {
  $(this).parents('tr').remove();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  var total = 0;
  $('.Debit').each(function() {
    total += parseFloat($(this).val());
    $('.sum_of_Debit').val(total);
  });
  $(".Debit").on("change keyup", function() { 
    var sum = 0;
    sum += parseFloat($('.sum_of_ Debit').val());
    $('.sum_of_Debit').val(sum);
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  var total = 0;
  $('.credit').each(function() {
    total += parseFloat($(this).val());
    $('.sum_of_credit').val(total);
  });
  $(".credit").on("change keyup", function() { 
    var sum = 0;
    sum += parseFloat($('.sum_of_credit').val());
    $('.sum_of_credit').val(sum);
  });
});
```

```html
<table id="dynamic">
  <tr>
    <th class="wd-15p fontColor">credit</th>
    <th class="wd-15p fontColor">Debit</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="td"><input type="number" value="1000" class="form-control credit" /></td>
    <td class="td"><input type="number" value="1000"class="form-control Debit" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="td"><input type="number" value="1000" class="form-control credit" /></td>
    <td class="td"><input type="number" value="1000"  class="form-control Debit" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="td"><input type="number" value="1000" class="form-control credit" /></td>
    <td class="td"><input type="number" value="1000" class="form-control Debit" /></td>
    <td class="td2"><button type="button" name="add" id="add-btn" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input type="text" class="form-control sum_of_credit" readonly>
<input type="text" class="form-control sum_of_Debit" readonly>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

**What is required ???** I want to get the total sum of the values inside the inputs in each of the following cases: When changing any value in the input, the total of values should be re-sum based on the values that were entered. And when adding a new dynamic row and writing new values in the new input this value should be added to the sum total, that is, the total should be recalculated and this new value that was entered should be included in the total sum. When deleting a dynamic row, the sum should be recalculated and the values that were in the deleted row should be excluded, i.e. the value of this row should be deleted from the grand total.

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. It should not simply list your requirements. Also, your script seems to have some awkward nesting. The second click function and the ready function are inside the first click function. A good editor and proper formatting make this apparent.

Comment: They are not actually inside the the 1st click function but yeah the formatting is pretty messy and makes the code kind of unreadable, I fixed his format to make it work if someone can accept my edit

Comment: The question still lacks one thing and that is your attempt to solve the problem, where are you stuck? what error msg do you get?

Comment: Don't just edit your code without trying your snippet and messing everything up `$('.sum_of_amount' ').val(sum).toFixed(2);` this is wrong after your edit

Comment: @ChrisG  Thank you for your comments, modifications and improvements to my code. I apologize because I am new to the platform and do not know the laws of writing code. And What is required??? I wont to  get the total sum of the values inside the inputs in each of the following cases: when changing the values of the inputs, when adding a new dynamic row, when deleting a dynamic row . In all of the following cases, the total sum of the input values should be obtained

Comment: Almost got it, hold on a few min

Comment: @ChrisG I have explained the question in more depth and detail, please take a look at the question & code  again.

Comment: @ChrisG Have you looked at the modifications I made to the code??

Comment: yes however, the code I made is still incomplete, I can post it and see if you can keep working from there. At least until I have the time to look into it

Comment: @ChrisG Thank you very much my friend for this help. You really owe me that....

Comment: @ChrisG How can I avoid `NaN` when I empty any input ? I noticed in the code that you made that when I empty the content of any input, it appears to me in the field displaying the total sum, `NaN` . How can avoid the appearance of `NaN` ?

Comment: You can add `|| 0` to the `parseFloat` method here check my answer after update

Comment: @ChrisG Yes it has been working well. Thank you again

Comment: @ChrisG Unfortunately, when modifying the input values of a new dynamic row, the sum is not updated

Comment: @ChrisG The automatic sum update does not work when modifying the value of any new dynamic field

Comment: @ChrisG Iam just added this and the code working fine `$("body").on('keyup change', '.credit, .Debit', function (){
reCalculate();
});`

Comment: Is not working, is giving `NaN` and is not adding the event handler to the new elements

Comment: Check the update now, Is finally working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** Fixed the issue, event is added to all elements now

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  reCalculate();

  $("#add-btn").click(function() {
    $("#dynamic").append('<tr>' +
      '<td class="td">' +
      '<input type="number" value= "1000" name="quantity" class="form-control quantity"/>' +
      '</td>' +
      '<td class = "td" >' +
      '<input type = "number" value = "1000" name = "amount" class = "form-control amount"/>' +
      '</td>' +
      '<td class = "td2" >' +
      '<button type = "button" name = "add" class = "btn btn-danger remove-tr" > Remove </button>' +
      '</td>' +
      '</tr>');
    reCalculate();
  });

  // Add on change/keyup to dynamically added elements with event delegation like this
  $('#dynamic').on('change keyup', '.quantity, .amount', function() {
    reCalculate();
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.remove-tr', function() {
    $(this).parents('tr').remove();
    reCalculate();
  });

  function reCalculate() {
    let totalQty = 0;
    let amountQty = 0;

    $('.quantity').each(function() {
      totalQty += parseFloat($(this).val() || 0);
      $('.sum_of_quantity').val(totalQty);
    });

    $('.amount').each(function() {
      amountQty += parseFloat($(this).val() || 0);
      $('.sum_of_amount').val(amountQty);
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="dynamic">
  <tr>
    <th class="wd-15p fontColor">Quantity</th>
    <th class="wd-15p fontColor">Amount</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="td"><input type="number" value="1000" name="quantity[]" class="form-control quantity" /></td>
    <td class="td"><input type="number" value="1000" name="amount[]" class="form-control amount" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="td"><input type="number" value="1000" name="quantity[]" class="form-control quantity" /></td>
    <td class="td"><input type="number" value="1000" name="amount[]" class="form-control amount" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="td"><input type="number" value="1000" name="quantity[]" class="form-control quantity" /></td>
    <td class="td"><input type="number" value="1000" name="amount[]" class="form-control amount" /></td>
    <td class="td2"><button type="button" name="add" id="add-btn" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control sum_of_quantity" readonly> </td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control sum_of_amount" readonly></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to your code :

```
$("body").on('keyup change', '.credit, .Debit', function (){
reCalculate();
});
```